# Linq to xml select list of nodes based on child attribute

Tags: c#, linq

I have been learning LINQ to XML however I ran into a senario where I'm a little stuck.

If I have the following XML:

```
<root>
    <planes />
    <trains />
    <cars>
        <car name="civic">      
            <property name="4doors" />
            <property name="4tires" />
        </car>
        <car name="f150">
            <property name="2doors" />
            <property name="4tires" />
        </car>
        <car name="crv">
            <property name="4doors" />
            <property name="4tires" />
        </car>      
        <car name="scooter">
            <property name="2tires" />
        </car>      
        <car name="escape">
            <property name="4doors" />
            <property name="4tires" />
        </car>
    </cars>
</root>
```

How can I return a list of cars who has 4doors?

So far I've tried the following attempts:

```
// This will return a list of nulls

    var fourDoorCars = xDoc.Descendants("cars").Descendants("car").Descendants("property").Where(x => x.Attribute("name").Value.Contains("4doors")).Select(x => x.Element("car")).ToList();

// This will return a list of all the 4doors properties.

    var fourDoorCars = xDoc.Descendants("cars").Descendants("car").Descendants("property").Where(x => x.Attribute("name").Value.Contains("4doors")).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var query=xDoc.Descendants("car")
              .Where(x=> x.Elements("property")
                          .Any(y=>y.Attribute("name").Value.Contains("4doors")));
```